# Collecting AWS Route 53 DNS Queries with Splunk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently trying to set up a Splunk server, running on an AWS EC2 instance to collect data from AWS. For CloudTrail, VPC Flowlogs, and general CloudWatch logs it works just fine, but I'm currently a bit struggling getting Route 53 DNS query logs to work.

I can see those logs in the CloudWatch dashboard, as they get delivered to N. Virginia by default. I also chose these settings in the Splunk dashboard and it also let me choose Route 53 in the advanced section, but still no DNS logs in Splunk.

Also I'm not sure if the default 'HealthCheckId' dimension is correct, with the corresponding '[{"HealthCheckId":[".*"]}]' dimension value.

Maybe someone had the same issue and could point out my mistake, as I can't really find something online and I have no clue anymore what else to change.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out myself.

I chose the wrong input format, the right one would have been "VPC Flow Logs" and then "CloudWatch Logs", configuring the right Log Group and region of course.

Now everything gets imported as it should and can be searched and displayed in Splunk.